# Java: sort multidimensional by two columns and set specific row on top

Tags: java, sorting

Let's say I have this array:

```
[
  ['Chief 1', 'Chief 1'],
  ['Employee 5', 'Chief 2'],
  ['Employee 4', 'Chief 1'],
  ['Employee 2', 'Chief 1'],
  ['Chief 2', 'Chief 2'],
]
```

My goal:

```
[
    ['Chief 1', 'Chief 1'],
    ['Employee 2', 'Chief 1'],
    ['Employee 4', 'Chief 1'],
    ['Chief 2', 'Chief 2'],
    ['Employee 5', 'Chief 2'],
]
```

I want to group each employee by his chief so I want to sort the array based on the alphabetical order and also keep the chief on the top.
This what I did so far but it's still not working as expected:

```
Object[][] data = new Object[2][5];
// after filling the data array
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
                    String employee1 = (String) o1[0];
                    String employee2 = (String) o2[0];
                    String chief1 = (String) o1[1];
                    String chief2 = (String) o2[1];

                    if(employee1.equals(chief1)){// column 1 equal to column 2 so this is a chief and must stay first
                        return -1;
                    }else{
                        if(chief1.equals(chief2)){// if row 1 equals row 2 so it's the same chief then compare by employe
                            return employee1.compareTo(employee2);
                        }
                        return chief1.compareTo(chief2);// else compare by chief
                    }
                }
            });
```

This keeps sorting by alphabetical order and I don't get the chief on the top of the array.
**EDIT**:
This is a real example of chiefs and employees:

```
[
['AMRI Kamel', 'BRAHMI Younes']
['BOULAHMI Fathi', 'BRAHMI Younes']
['BRAHMI Younes', 'BRAHMI Younes']
['ECHI Younes', 'BRAHMI Younes']
['FERCHICHI Khomsi', 'BRAHMI Younes']
['ABDI Hsan ', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['BEN MABROUK Houssem', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['HARMI Sami', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['JBELI Hatem', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['JBELI Rached', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['LAABIDI Faiek', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['LAHBIBI Faouzi', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['MLIKI Marouen', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['NACEUR Mohamed Ali ', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['NEFZI Mustapha', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['OUERGHI Sami ', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['SASSI Lamjed', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['SASSI Mohamed', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['ZEDDINI Achref ', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['ZOUARI Mohamed Ali ', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
['ZRIBI  Bilel', 'NACEUR Mohamed Ali ']
]
```

In this example I have two chiefs `BRAHMI Younes` and `NACEUR Mohamed Ali` my current code gives me this result they are sorted by alphabetical order but the chiefs are not displayed on the top of their employees.

Comment: Instead of using "chief #" as the second dimension, could you just use the number and sort by it? (i.e.[ 'Chief 1', 1], ['employee 1', 1]...['employee 5', 2])

Comment: @DanielGale no I can't it must be strings

Comment: Are all the `Chief #`s guaranteed to be lexicographically smaller than any given `Employee #`?

Comment: @JanezKuhar I have edited my question you can find a real example of my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
                String employee1 = (String) o1[0];
                String employee2 = (String) o2[0];
                String chief1 = (String) o1[1];
                String chief2 = (String) o2[1];

                if(chief1.equals(chief2))
                    // same chief, sort by empolyee keeping Chief at top
                    if(employee1.equals(chief1))
                        return -1;
                    else if(employee2.equals(chief2))
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return employee1.compareTo(employee2);
                else
                    // if chiefs aren't equals, sort relying on them
                    return chief1.compareTo(chief2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I will try it but I don't think it will keep the chief on the top of his employees

Comment: Nope, the chief still does not appear on the top of his employees

Comment: You were right, my bad I skipped that part of the question. With the edit should work tho

Comment: My bad again, didn't see the op edit on the question

Comment: @LucaNegrini but the chief names does not starts with `Chief` it's just an example I gave, I have edited my question you can see a real example of my situation

Comment: if(employee1.equals(chief1)) not if(employee1.equals(employee1).

Comment: Sorry still does not keep the chief on the top of his employees :(

Comment: @DanielGale you're right that line makes the difference now it's working right

Comment: @LucaNegrini `DanielGale`'s comment make it right thanks for both of you for your times guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what you want to do is **sort** the rows and **group by** *chiefs*. This could be done a lot cleaner using the **Java8 streams**.

Say you define an auxiliary class `Relation` to represent each row:

```
class Relation implements Comparable<Relation> {
    String chief;        
    String employee;

    public Relation(String[] row) {
        employee = row[0];            
        chief = row[1];
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Relation other) {
        return chief.equals(employee) ? -1 : employee.compareTo(other.employee);        
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s]", employee, chief);
    }
}
```

Given a *list* of `Relation` rows (call it `relations`, lets say), you can print the desired result like so:

```
relations.stream()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.chief))
    .values().stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This really looks cleaner but I don't think it will keep the chief on the top of his employees no matter what his name is. am i right ?

Comment: @SlimenTN Yes, it will.